# --workerCacheMB setting missing in apache beam 0.6?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In Google Cloud Dataflow 1.x, I presumably had access to this critical pipeline option called:

`workerCacheMb`

I tried to set in in my beam 0.6 pipeline, but couldn't do so (it said that no such option existed.). I then scoured through the options source code to see if any option had a similar name -- but I still couldn't find it.

I need to set it as I think that my worfklow's incredibly slowness is due to a side input that 3GB but that appears to be taking well over 20 minutes to read. (I have a View.asList() and then I'm trying to do a for-loop on the list -- it's taking more than 20 minutes and still going; even at 3 GB, that's way too slow.) So, I was hoping that setting the workerCacheMb would help. (The only other theory I have is to switch from serializablecoder to AvroCoder....)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the right class of options?

The following code works for me in Beam:

```
    DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create()
            .cloneAs(DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions.class);

    options.setWorkerCacheMb(3000);
```